# Password protect launch of android application

Tags: android

I'm searching for a way to password protect my android application on launch, i.e. when launching/resuming an activity belonging to my apk-package a password dialog will be shown.

I've tried some approaches to this (extending [application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and so on) but none seems to work. Either they don't run on the UI thread or the dialog isn't shown on every launch/resume occasion.

// m

Comment: Application class is the way to go, please post what/how you have tried, the code. As it might be something wrong with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So this is the solution I stuck with. In my Application class i store a long variable with the system time when an activity was last paused.

```
import android.app.Application;
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public long mLastPause;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mLastPause = 0;
        Log.w("Application","Launch");
    }
}
```

In every onPause-method I update this value to the current time.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ((MyApplication)this.getApplication()).mLastPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

And in every onResume I compare it to the current time. If a certain amount of time (currently 5 seconds) has passed my password prompt is shown.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication app = ((MyApplication)act.getApplication());
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - app.mLastPause > 5000) {
        // If more than 5 seconds since last pause, prompt for password
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I think there is a little thing missing: the code in the `onResume` function should also be executed in the `onStart` function. I had to add this part in order to avoid an annoying case: the lock was not displayed once the app was reopened after a clean exit.

Comment: @YoannHercouet I'm not so sure that's needed. From what I've understood the onResume method will be called after the onStart method on cold starts. See this illustration from the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: Also instead of modifying onResume and onPause of all your Activities, you can create a LockActivity class with the needed Overidden methods and make all your activities extend that class.

Comment: @KhaledZarrad can you please give an example of creating Lock Activty and overiding the methods.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass Application, and set a variable in there on whether the next time something happens in your app, you should prompt a dialog or not.

In your Activity, Service, etc... using the Context you receive, get your Application, if the var is set to show the dialog, from your Activity code (meaning the UI Thread) show your dialog. You'd probably put this in your onResume code.

In onPause, set the variable to show it next time. In onResume, set it as false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing though... There doesn't seem to be an application-wide onPause and onResume which means I have to set the variable in each activity. This will cause the password dialog to show every time a new activity is launched/resumed. Just setting the variable in the Application class' onCreate will only work when the application is cold-started which probably won't be too often. Correct me if I'm wrong :-)

Comment: You'll have to make it a bit smarter. Have a counter instead of a boolean. Every time an onResume happens, increase it, every time an onPause happens, decrease it. If its 0 when an activity starts, show the password.

Comment: Okay, now I've implemented your solution and it still doesn't work since on every start/resume of an activity (even when called from another activity) the password prompt is shown. This happens because the calling activity's onPause is executed before the initiating onResume which means that the variable always will be 0 on activity launch.

onPause:
    ((MyApplication)this.getApplication()).mActivityCounter--;

onResume:
    MyApplication app = ((MyApplication)act.getApplication());
    if (app.mActivityCounter == 0) {
      // Do password check
    }
    app.mActivityCounter++;

Any idea?

Comment: Well, you could always just keep a boolean in your Application and set it false on init, true when you enter the password. When all services, providers, and activities are killed later, the application will also die so that the next time anything starts the boolean will be reset.

Comment: Yes that could be one solution but I then still have the problem when the app is just paused in the background for a long time withouth the user's knowledge (and as I have understood they most often are). Anyway, the Application class still seems like the right way to go so I will have to continue experiment with it. Thanks for all help so far (more ideas is of course welcome ;-))