# Follow up on Password protect launch of android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Following up on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448189, what is the best way to actually *show* the password screen?

My first try was starting a SubActivity with a LockActivity:

```
// MainActivity.java
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ApplicationState state = ((ApplicationState) getApplication());
    if ((new Date().getTime() - state.mLastPause) > 5000) {

        // Prompt for password if more than 5 seconds since last pause
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, UNLOCKED);
    }
}
```

However, this causes the MainActivity to be paused again after getting unlocked if the LockActivity is shown longer than 5 seconds.

So, I have some things in mind:

1. Use `Fragments` to show the Main screen or the Lock screen inside of MainActivity.
2. Show a `Dialog` as Lock screen (not preferred).
3. Using several `if ... else` branches to check whether a password has been set **and** the MainActivity has been paused longer than five seconds.

To give you an example, I would like to achieve the same behavior as in the Dropbox app (using the "Passcode lock" option).

What is the correct way to handle this?

P.S. I'm not sure whether I should have posted this as a question to the original question, thus digging out the old thread. I felt like posting a new question is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why do you not prefer a Dialog solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since I was the one asking the other question, I might as well tell you how I solved it. I'm using a dialog for prompting for the password (which I do know you do not prefer, but it might help someone else) and makes sure that the only way to dismiss it is by entering the correct password.

```
MyApplication app = ((MyApplication)getApplication());
if (new Date().getTime() - app.mLastPause > 5000) {
  // If more than 5 seconds since last pause, check if password is set and prompt if necessary
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String password = pref.getString("password", "");
  if (password.length() > 0) {
     // Prompt for password
     MyPasswordDialog dlg = new MyPasswordDialog(this, password);
     dlg.setOwnerActivity(this);
     dlg.show();
  }
}
```

And in the `OnCreate()`-method of MyPasswordDialog i make sure that it is not cancelable

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   this.setCancelable(false);
   // ...and some other initializations
}
```